# What is lodash's "nth" function good for?

Tags: javascript, lodash

The lodash function `_.nth(array, n)` returns the nth item of the array. I'm struggling to imagine any circumstance where this function would be preferable to simply writing `array[n]`.

Even with the overhead of writing a lambda function, the native syntax is shorter. For example, to sort an array of arrays by their fifth element:

```
_.sortBy(array, _.partial(_.nth(_, 5)));
_.sortBy(array, x => x[5]);
```

The second version is significantly shorter, more readable, and faster.

What would be an example of a situation where it might be preferable to use this function?

Comment: the `fp` version of `nth` may have the argument reversed such that you don't need `_.partial`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on mpen's comment, I think `_.nth` is more useful in `lodash/fp`, where it can be used akin to Python's `itemgetter`.

```
let sortByHead = _.sortBy(_.nth(0));

sortByHead([[0, 1], [-1, 2], [3, 4]]);
// [ [ -1, 2 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 3, 4 ] ]
```

In vanilla Lodash, as far as I can tell, its usefulness is limited to negative indexing.

Comment: There are a few great answers here, but I hadn't even known about lodash/fp (it's not mentioned in the main documentation!) and looking at it now, it feels like it's exactly what I was expecting lodash to be about all along!

Answer (score 4):

> If n is negative, the nth element from the end is returned.

This mimics Ruby-style array index semantics, and can be useful for less verbose code when you need to index from the right-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

_.nth is usefull for chaining

*without _.nth*

```
var secondItem = _.chain(data)
    .filter()
    .map()
    .value()[1];
var neededValue = _.chain(secondItem)
    .reduce()
    .filter()
    .value();
```

*with _.nth*

```
var neededValue = _.chain(data)
    .filter()
    .map()
    .nth(1)
    .reduce()
    .filter()
    .value();
```